# how to install missing jenkins plugins, when using gradlew?

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, groovy, gradlew

When I try to run

> gradlew 'task'

I get this following error message:

(I am obviously missing some jenkins plugins)

```
* What went wrong:
Error resolving plugin [id: 'com.terrafolio.jenkins', version: '1.3.2'].
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration1'.
  > Could not find org.jenkins-ci.plugins:job-dsl-core:1.42.
    Searched in the following locations:
      https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/jenkins-ci/plugins/job-dsl-
         core/1.42/job-dsl-core-1.42.pom
      https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/jenkins-ci/plugins/job-dsl-
         core/1.42/job-dsl-core-1.42.jar
    Required by:
      unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.terrafolio:gradle-jenkins-plugin:1.3.2
```

My task looks like this: (running a groovy script)

```
task testDeployOsb << {
javaexec {
  classpath = configurations.osb
  main = 'groovy.ui.GroovyMain'
  args = ["support-scripts/deployAlsb.groovy",
        "${buildDir}/deployment.groovy"]
  jvmArgs = ["-Dweblogic.MaxMessageSize=200000000",
           "-Dweblogic.CompleteT3MessageTimeout=480",
           "-Dweblogic.CompleteMessageTimeout=480",
           "-Dweblogic.wsee.transport.read.timeout=600000",
           "-Dweblogic.wsee.transport.connection.timeout=600000"]
  }
}
```

So how do I install said plugins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have define at least one repository that can serve the external plugin. [Maven Central seems to have it](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.terrafolio%22%20AND%20a%3A%22gradle-jenkins-plugin%22). Also the Gradle plugin portal hosts the plugin. You can find the notation for including it [here](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.terrafolio.jenkins).